# Expect script with encrypted passwords returning string with single quotes

Tags: bash, openssl, exec, expect

I am trying to use an expect script to pull configs from cisco devices. Dont ask why the client does not use a standard tool.

My issue is that they wish to use encrypted passwords for the session. I can encrypt and salt the password into a file and then use cat within the expect script to pull out the password into a variable... see code below, however, the exec command puts the string value into single quotes. Expect scripts I believe treat single quotes differently to double and certainly not like a string.

I can validate that the rest of the code works by putting the raw password into the script as a substitude and if I use 'puts' to display the variable it displays
'password'

My thought as I said is that the exec command is then putting the string back with the single quotes around them.

I have tried SED and TR piped into the end of the command string but that still gives the same result as I would expect.

Any thoughts

```
set salt "mrsalty"
set admincmd "cat /mrpwd.txt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -salt -pass pass:$salt"
set password [ exec sh -c $admincmd ]
```

Comment: expect is a tcl extension, and single quotes have no special meaning in tcl (Unlike double quotes), yes. The exec command doesn't add anything around what the executed command returns.

Comment: You can use just `set password [exec cat /mrpwd.txt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -salt -pass pass:$salt]` btw.

Comment: Or, without cat `set password [exec openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -salt -pass pass:$salt -in /mrpwd.txt]`

Answer (score 0):

(This is not really an answer, more of a long, formatted comment)

> the exec command puts the string value into single quotes

No it does not.
A demo:

First, create an encrypted password file in the shell

```sh
$ salt=mrsalty
$ echo MyPass1234 | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -e -salt -pass pass:$salt > pw.encrypted
$ cat pw.encrypted
U2FsdGVkX18bFSAmQbXqGjeSBVtE8AzJ2K8Lif4muB8=
```

Now in expect

```
expect1.1> set salt mrsalty
mrsalty
expect1.2> set file pw.encrypted
pw.encrypted
expect1.3>  set password [exec openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -salt -pass pass:$salt -in $file]
MyPass1234
```

No single quotes there.

Even with storing the command in a variable and using sh

```
expect1.4>  set admincmd "cat $file | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -salt -pass pass:$salt"
cat pw.encrypted | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -salt -pass pass:mrsalty
expect1.5> set password [exec sh -c $admincmd]
MyPass1234
```

How are you **using** $password later in the expect code?

Comment: Thanks, in fact your comment provoked me to start again from scratch and I noticed that in fact, the origional text I had been sent to create the salted/encrypted password file  was with the wrong quotes meaning that the password itself in the file had quotes around it. . PIBKAC Error here so apologies.

Comment: Please update your question, or provide an answer so future readers don't have to get through a whole question and answer to discover it was a typo.